# I was trying to fetch all user Data in Transactions Table but it kept showing only One Row

Tags: php

I needed to fetch all user data from the Database by email as my unique ID but it kept showing one Row

Here is my query function:

```
 public function fetchAirtimeTrans() {

        $email = $_SESSION['logged'];

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE `email` = '$email' ORDER BY id ASC ");
        $query->execute();
        $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = $query->fetchAll();

        return $result;

        
    }
```

and here's the result am getting:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqGeS.png)

and my Database Transaction Table:
[transactions table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84PiT.png)

and my Index File with Table:

```
$datas = new Transactions();
$result = $datas->fetchAirtimeTrans();

if($result) {

    foreach( $result as $row) {
    }
    ?>
<?php
<tr>
<td> <?= $row[trans_id] </td>

</td>
</tr>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming it's not a typo, it should be

```php
$datas = new Transactions();
$result = $datas->fetchAirtimeTrans();

if($result) {

    foreach( $result as $row) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row['trans_id'];?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
```

- the **trans_id** is a string and needs to be quoted
- the table row/data need to be within the loop, before the brace
- and `<?php` and `?>` were not correct
- there was an extra `</td>`

Comment: yes that's the issue. I misplaced the brace. It all done now